# I am having trouble while converting Integer to string

Tags: java, string, jframe, jlabel

So, im making a program in which whenever a button is clicked 3 is added to an integer called Score
so that if the button is clicked 2 times score will be 6.I made the score int final int with value of 0.

Ok the syntax i added was

- To add 3: `Viewablescore[0] =+ 3;`
- For console `System.out.println(Viewablescore);`
- for JFrame `label2.setText(String.valueOf(Viewablescore));`

I wanted to print the result on both console and in the Jframe, but i was given with `[I@563bf420`.
The program ran successfully.
What should i do

Comment: The other way around. `+=`, not `=+`. This way to avoid cinfusion with setting the value to `+3` (which is what your code does).

Comment: You said your int is final, You cannot change the value of a final variable. I suggest you read about [variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Comment: Are you using an array but only using element 0 of the array? What’s the point of using an array, then?

Comment: Cardinal Hey! i tried using a local var but rather than adding it it simply just printed the value of the button i clicked

Comment: @OleV.V. What should i do then?

Comment: Assuming that you have told us all that you want to obtain and your code isn’t multi-threaded, then just use a (non-final) `int` variable and add 3 to it when the button is clicked. Then it is trivial to print it. And still use `String.valueOf()` to put it in the label.